# MSBuild to copy dynamically generated files as part of project dependency

Tags: c#, msbuild, build-process

I have a custom msbuild task that is generating some output files to the output directory ($(TargetDir)) of a ProjectA. Current code is something like this:

```
<MyCustomTask ...>
   <Output TaskParameter="OutputFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
</MyCustomTask>
```

A ProjectB is referencing *ProjectA* but the problem is that when building ProjectB, generated files by MyCustomTask are not copied to the output directory of the ProjectB.

How can we get dynamically generated additional files to be copied as part of project dependency with MSBuild?

Comment: Here is a similar question that resulted in slightly different approach https://stackoverflow.com/q/44752139/165500 that might be handy for cases where a custom task is not involved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have finally managed to perform automatically the copy from *Project B* without having to modify it. IIya was not so far from the solution, but the fact is that I cannot generate statically  as the list of files to generate from *Project A* with MyCustomTask is dynamic. After digging more into `Microsoft.Common.targets`, I have found that ProjectB will get the list of output from *Project A* by calling the target `GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems`. This target is dependent from `AssignTargetPaths` which itself is dependent on the target list property `AssignTargetPathsDependsOn`.

So in order to generate dynamically content and to get this content being copied automatically through standard project dependency, we need to hook *Project A* at two different places:

- In `AssignTargetPathsDependsOn` as it is called indirectly by *Project B* on *Project A* through GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems. And also it is indirectly called by *Project A* when `PrepareResource` is called. Here, we are just outputing the list of files that will be generated (by *Project A*) or consumed by *Project B*. AssignTargetPathsDependsOn will call a custom task `MyCustomTaskList` which is only responsible to output the list of files (but not to generate them), this list of files will create dynamic "Content" with `CopyOutputDirectory`.
- In `BuildDependsOn` in order to actually generate the content in *Project A*. This will call `MyCustomTask` that will generate the content.

All of this was setup like this in ProjectA:

```xml
<!-- In Project A -->

<!-- Task to generate the files -->
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTask" AssemblyFile="$(PathToMyCustomTaskAssembly)"/>

<!-- Task to output the list of generated of files - It doesn't generate the file -->
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTaskList" AssemblyFile="$(PathToMyCustomTaskAssembly)"/>

<!-- 1st PART : When Project A is built, It will generate effectively the files -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    MyCustomTaskTarget;
    $(BuildDependsOn);
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyCustomTaskTarget">
  <!-- Call MyCustomTask generate the files files that will be generated by MyCustomTask -->
  <MyCustomTask
      ProjectDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"
      IntermediateDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
      Files="@(MyCustomFiles)"
      RootNamespace="$(RootNamespace)"
      >
  </MyCustomTask>
</Target>

<!-- 2nd PART : When Project B is built, It will call GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems on ProjectA so we need to generate this list when it is called  -->
<!-- For this we need to override AssignTargetPathsDependsOn in order to generate the list of files -->
<!-- as GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems  ultimately depends on AssignTargetPathsDependsOn -->
<!-- Content need to be generated before AssignTargets, because AssignTargets will prepare all files to be copied later by GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems -->
<!-- This part is also called from ProjectA when target 'PrepareResources' is called -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssignTargetPathsDependsOn>
    $(AssignTargetPathsDependsOn);
    MyCustomTaskListTarget;
  </AssignTargetPathsDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyCustomTaskListTarget">

  <!-- Call MyCustomTaskList generating the list of files that will be generated by MyCustomTask -->
  <MyCustomTaskList
      ProjectDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"
      IntermediateDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
      Files="@(MyCustomFiles)"
      RootNamespace="$(RootNamespace)"
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="ContentFiles" ItemName="MyCustomContent"/>
  </MyCustomTaskList>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--Generate the lsit of content generated by MyCustomTask -->
    <Content Include="@(MyCustomContent)" KeepMetadata="Link;CopyToOutputDirectory"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This method is working with anykind of C# projects that is using Common.Targets (so It is working with pure Desktop, WinRT XAML App or Windows Phone 8 projects).

Comment: Be aware that `AssignTargetPathsDependsOn` trick was broken by .NET SDK, see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1558) for help.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this seems to work, either include it manually into ProjectA's .csproj (keep in mind VS has a bad habit of occasionally resolving wildcards into absolute paths and overwriting .csproj) or inject dynamically by the custom task itself. Also, VS caches itemgroups on open, so it might not copy the files or fail the build if they were there but deleted. In that case projects need to be reloaded or VS restarted for itemgroups to be reevaluated. MSBuild, TFS, etc should always work.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(TargetDir)\*.txt">
    <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Not so far, but I can't generate this list statically as you did. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you already doing this build yourself with MSBuild, could you add a [Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) to push the files around yourself?

Comment: I guess the question is how to configure the task so it actually copies files into target of ProjectB. Or more likely marks files in ProjectA folder somehow so ProjectB to copy files similar to references and other files with "copy to output Directory=always".

Comment: @Wolfwyrd, as Alexei said, your solution implies that I would have to modify ProjectB to perform the copy but I would like to avoid this. The "FileWrites" seems only to be used for tracking files when using "Clean" target but is not used for registering outputs. The Microsoft.Common.targets file seems to perform some specific operations to copy dependencies, and It is not clear that it is extendable to handle this.

Comment: @xoofx - so ProjectB contains your invocation of MyCustomTask at some point? Why can't you just put a <Copy> task invocation in the same target after MyCustomTask? Or why not just, in your code in MyCustomTask, do the copy via your favorite .NET copy API?

Comment: No Project B contains a regular ProjectReference dependency to Project A. But Project B doesn't know what Project A is actually doing (MyCustomTask or not). The solution requires a bit more hooking in msbuild, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, if I placed a `<None Link="..." />` within a target, I'm able to get the output processed without it showing up in my SDK based project. 
Additionally, other projects that reference this project gets this as part of the output.

E.g.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <WebPackBuildOutput Include="..\..\WebPackOutput\dist\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="WebPackOutputContentTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
        <Message Text="Output dynamic content: @(WebPackBuildOutput)" Importance="high"/>
        <ItemGroup>
            <!-- Manually constructing Link metadata, works in classic projects as well -->
            <None Include="@(WebPackBuildOutput)" Link="dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
        </ItemGroup>        
    </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to add additional step by writing only this line in ProjectB.msbuild:

```
<Import Project="ProjectA.msbuild" />
```

To achieve it you can write something like in ProjectA:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn);MyCustomTask</BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This adds your task to the list of dependencies of Build task.

Refer this question for details:
[StyleCop MS Build magic? Who is calling the StyleCop target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343340/stylecop-ms-build-magic-who-is-calling-the-stylecop-target)

Comment: Not really. I want to dynamically generate some content in Project A that will get copied by Project B, without having to modify Project B. The Project B has only a ProjectReference dependency, but in no way It has to know that Project A is generating dynamically some content.