# How to copy output of referenced project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have two projects: `Lib` and `Exe`.

Project `Lib` generates some files in `PostBuildEvent`  into `$(TargetDir)`. Assume it's

```
echo Foo > $(TargetDir)\Readme.txt
```

`Exe` references `Lib` with `Copy Local` set to`True`.

Unfortunately no files are copied to `Exe`'s output dir.

How can I teach VS/MSBuild to copy my files just like it copies project items with `Copy to Output Directory` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSBuild to copy dynamically generated files as part of project dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322391/msbuild-to-copy-dynamically-generated-files-as-part-of-project-dependency)

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done if you add an `AfterBuild` target in your Visual Studio project file of `Exe` project like below:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <LibProject Include="$(LibProjectDirectory)\Lib.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <LibOutput Include="%(LibProject.RootDir)%(LibProject.Directory)\bin\$(Configuration)\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(LibOutput)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
  </Target>
```

This assumes that `Lib` project output is going to the default location of `%(LibProject.RootDir)%(LibProject.Directory)\bin\$(Configuration)`. If it is configured differently you need to update the `LibOutput` Item's `Include` parameter accordingly.