# MSBuild to include dynamically generated files as part of project dependency when the dynamic files are in the bin directory

Tags: msbuild

An extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322391), but slightly different, and the accepted answer does not quite work for this situation.

We've got a process in place on the build of our project which is generating some additional files, these files are getting (correctly) generated into the `/bin` folder as expected. However they are not getting copied across when this project is referenced as a dependency.

Following the above questions accepted answer (with a little bit of tweaking), I managed to get them copying across to the dependant project **however** they are all getting put into a `/bin` sub folder of the dependants `/bin` folder (i.e. `/bin/bin`), which is not what I need to have happen.

The process we're running is a 3<sup>rd</sup> party process (specifically [Surviveplus.XmlCommentLocalization](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Surviveplus.XmlCommentLocalization/)), so I have no control over that side of it.

I could do something additional on the dependant project to move them out of the `/bin/bin` into the level up, but I'd rather have the original project work as I'd expect it to.

This is the `ItemGroup` I'm using, derived from the other question:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*\*.xml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I've also tried setting specifically the `TargetPath` value, which while un-documented (or I'm blind to it), seems to exist - as per the msbuild output log

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*\*.xml" KeepMetadata="TargetPath">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <TargetPath>..\</TargetPath>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

But it appears that when it comes to the `Copy` task it just ignores it, and resolves a new `TargetPath`. I've also tried a myriad of combinations of attributes/item types in that item group (i.e. None, EmbeddedResource) but they didn't solve it either.

Ideally I suppose MSBuild needs to mark the generated files as part of the generated assembly? But after getting lost in `.target` files and MSDN docs, I couldn't figure it out.

MSBuild being used is version 12.0, compiling for .net4.5.

Comment: it's amazing no one knows the answer for this one.
I'm looking for an answer just like you.