# Publishing log files

Tags: asp.net, iis, log4net

I am trying to publish log files generated by my webapp using log4net.
I suppose IIS does not publish it by default, is there a way to fix it ?

I know that there is a security break in publishing log files, any tip is welcome to watch these files without a risk...

Answer (score 0):

In general, you just need to add files to your project for them to be included in the WebDeploy package/deployment.

Comment: Log files are generated dynamically so I cannot add them before they are created.

Comment: You can dynamically add it via MSBuild as well. Checkout the second answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322391/msbuild-to-copy-dynamically-generated-files-as-part-of-project-dependency